# How to Upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10?

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, 13.10

I have tried installing all the available updates and when I check again for updates it says the computer is up to date. How can I upgrade?

Comment: sorry its not a duplicate the posts u mentioned have instructions to upgrade that's not my problem i cant find the upgrade in my software updater...

Comment: @maniteja you're asking how to upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10.  That thread is kinda explaining how to upgrade... so I'm kinda curious why that doesn't answer your question.